# C# How to get from json file list of nodes that contains specific key-value

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, deserialization

I have a json file like this:

```
[
    {
        "key1": {
            "find": 5,
            "count": 65,
            "name": "Parser"
        },
        "init": {
            "key2": {
                "find": 5,
                "count": 15,
                "name": "Some"
            },
            "arr": [
                    {
                    "key2": {
                        "find": 8,
                        "count": 32,
                        "name": "Object"
                    },
                    "temp": {
                        "pay": null
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "key3": {
            "find": 5,
            "count": 23,
            "name": "String"
        },
        "classes": [],
    }
]
```

And I want to get list of all nodes that contains key "find" and value "5". The result have to be:

```
{
    "find": 5,
    "count": 65,
    "name": "Parser"
},
{
    "find": 5,
    "count": 15,
    "name": "Some"
},
{
    "find": 5,
    "count": 23,
    "name": "String"
}
```

The difficulty is that the nesting can be any, but I need to get only those nodes that contain key "find" and the value "5" for it. How can I go through the entire file and get the nodes I need?

Comment: What had you tried so far? seems like simple tree traversal over json arrays and json objects ... you iterate array , if item is array you are calling recurivly if object then check for "find" in other case you are iterating properties, if property is json object you doing recursion if array then you start new array iteration ... if find json object which you want you put it to some container

Comment: Your json is not valid, pls post the real one

Comment: @Nika I am sorry but your json can not be  even parsed. I don't know how you did it.  try it here for example https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: What you called a random mistake  can need  the  completely different algorithm. It depends where to put curly brakets

Answer (score 1):

You can use JToken for this purpose, use the below function to find the nodes.

```
public void FindNodes(JToken json, string name, string value, List<JToken> nodes)
{
    if (json.Type == JTokenType.Object)
    {
        foreach (JProperty child in json.Children<JProperty>())
        {
            if (child.Name == name && child.Value.ToString() == value)
            {
                nodes.Add(child);
            }
            FindNodes(child.Value, name, value, nodes);
        }
    }
    else if (json.Type == JTokenType.Array)
    {
        foreach (JToken child in json.Children())
        {
            FindNodes(child, name, value, nodes);
        }
    }
}
```

Use the method in this way,

```
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(jsonString);
var nodes = new List<JToken>();
FindNodes(json, "find", "5", nodes);
```